# How can I create a search with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search

I'm new to angular I have a json data working with it in a ng repeat working find. Now I want to MAKE a search button where people can type a name and it will search through the json and pick the right one.

Comment: Are you asking how to search through a JSON-originated object in general, or how to integrate this with Angular? The two aren't really related at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example of filter, which you can use to search through json.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter